# Sum of three complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

We have three complex numbers $z_1, z_2, z_3$ such that $|z_1|=|z_3|=|z_3|=1$ and $z_1+z_2+z_3=1$. Find $$S={z_1}^{2013}+{z_2}^{2013}+{z_3}^{2013}$$
I would like only a hint. I probably know everything elementary about complex numbers so just give me a little kick start

Comment: Polar coordinates might be a hint, I think?

Comment: I thought about it. But I don't see how Moivre helps you here really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order that both the conditions $|z_1|=|z_3|=|z_3|=1$ and $z_1+z_2+z_3=1$ are satisfied, we require that $z_1,z_2,z_3$ and $1$ form a quadrilateral of four equal sides, therefore a rhombus.

Without loss of generality, we can have $z_1=e^{i\theta}, z_2=1,z_3=-e^{i\theta}$

Can you finish this?

Comment: That is nice. Thank you. I will take it from here!